# Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type x

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, bitwise-operators, operands

So I have some code in VB that I am trying to convert to C#. This code was written by someone else and I am trying to understand it but with some difficulty. I have some bitwise operator and enum comparison to do but keep throwing an error out:

I cannot say that i have used a lot of these syntaxes before and am baffled how to write this code. I have used Google to understand more about it and also used VB to C# online converters in the hopes of getting some basic guidance but nothing. The code below

**VB** - This is the original code that works

```
Flags = Flags And Not MyEnum.Value ' Flags is of type int
```

**C#** -the code I converted which is throwing an error

```
Flags = Flags & !MyEnum.Value; // Flags is of type int
```

**Error** - The error that is returned every time

> Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type MyEnum'.

Any help and some explanation on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `!` is not a bitwise operator, you probably meant `~`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!` can only operate on `bool` type. You seem to be operating on some bit flags. In that case you should use the bitwise NOT operator `~` instead of the logical NOT operator `!`:

```
Flags = Flags & ~((int)MyEnum.Value); // you need to cast to int as well
```

Comment: You'll need a cast of the enum value to an int.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas why do you say that?  I believe that is not true, as the underlying type of the enum would be an `int` and thus the `~` operator works just fine without casting.

Comment: @KirkWoll:  The bitwise operator '&' is not defined for int and any enum (this is the actual error you'll get), so you need to cast.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas not sure what you're talking about.  This works perfectly fine: `var foo = Foo.A | Foo.B;  foo = foo & ~Foo.A;`  Where `Foo` is declared as an `enum`.

Comment: Furthermore, of _course_ `&` is defined for `int`.  `int i = 0 & 5;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @KirkWoll Dave Doknjas is correct. All enums have a `~` operator that returns an enum, but overload resolution for `&` fails when you have an `int` and a `MyEnum`. Read the language spec section 7.5.3.

Comment: @Sweeper, like I said, `foo = foo & ~Foo.A` works perfectly fine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @KirkWoll: In your example, "foo" is not an int as in Sweeper's example - you'll notice that it's type is "Foo".  If you change "foo" to be of type int, you'll see the problem. In Sweeper's example, "Flags" is of type int.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  You are both right.  But it leaves the question as to why `Flags` is not declared as the actual enum type in that case where none of this would be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

To get the best conversion, it helps to first understand the implicit conversion that VB is doing for you:

```
Flags = Flags And Not (CInt(MyEnum.Value))
```

This is equivalent to the C# code:

```
Flags = Flags & ~(int)MyEnum.Value;
```

Which can be shortened:

```
Flags &= ~(int)MyEnum.Value;
```

In VB, "Not" is both the logical and bitwise operator, depending on context, but in C# you have two distinct operators.

Answer (score 5):

You maybe confusing *Logical* and *Bitwise* unary operators

Lets visit the help

[Operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/operators)

**Unary Operators**

- `+x`  Identity
- `-x`  Negation
- **`!x`    Logical negation**
- **`~x`    Bitwise negation**
- `++x` Pre-increment
- `--x` Pre-decrement
- `(T)x`    Explicitly convert x to type T

[Compiler Error CS0023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0023)

> Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operand of type 'type'
>
> An attempt was made to apply an operator to a variable whose type was
>   not designed to work with the operator.